# Is there any way to view the "Request Body " received by the server in the server logs

Tags: tomcat, post, request, server.xml

I am having trouble in logging the "Request body " sent to an engine that i created .

The engine is present as a war file (in webapps) and I want to access what request body was posted to the engine .

I get only this response in the " localhost_access_log.2017-12-28.txt " :

**192.168.3.206 - - [28/Dec/2017:16:38:09 +0530] "POST /Contract/getContractList HTTP/1.1" 200 1251733 - text/html;charset=UTF-8**

My server.xml has :
**pattern="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b %{Content-Type}i %{Content-Type}o  "**

My question is " Is there any way to get " request body " and/or "response body" in the server logs ?"